# What can I do to get an answer to this question?

Tags: support

I'm having a problem to which I tried to google a solution. The search turns up this question:

[Can't log in after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904378/cant-log-in-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-17-04/904399)

- This question precisely describes my own experience
- As the question author points out this is **not** a wrong password issue
- The duplicate question does not mention that the problem happened after upgrade to 17.04. Indeed it couldn't because 17.04 was not out yet when the question was asked. Thus, it's a different situation
- None of the suggestions in the duplicated question worked for me; I tried them all.

Since the question is closed as a duplicate, I won't get an answer there. I also won't get an answer at the duplicate, since it's already answered.

What options do I have to get my question answered? Creating another duplicate seems wrong, yet I cannot re-open the question, and I do not think editing other people's questions in this situation is the right thing to do.

So where do I go from here?

Comment: I suspect [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/629741/527764) to the canonical post is the relevant one. The canonical post is meant to be exhaustive. Any login loop solutions known to any user should be posted there. That's the principle anyway. The issue is almost certainly not specific to 17.04, though I suspect it is specific to running an upgrade from one release to another. (My suggested "fix" would be back up your `/home` and reinstall :S)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General answer

If your question *seems* to be a dupe, but the existing question/answer gives you no solution, the question is if it really is a dupe.

What I would suggest is to ask a new question, be very specific in under what circumstances your issue occurred, and also what possible dupe candidates you found. Mention that you tried the answer(s) and how, with what result.

What possibly happens then is:

- Someone will explain to you what you missed in the answers of the dupe candidate, your question will be duped.
- You will get a new answer, specific to your situation. In this case, it is extremely useful to edit the question and its title afterwards to distinguish from the dupe.
- In case of an existing canonical Q/A, someone might add an answer to the canonical one, to (also) catch your situation, or update an existing answer.

In all cases, the site is not harmed in anyway imo. On the contrary: either a useful signpost is created, or an additional Q/A is added to the site.